Converting to and from `bytes:Bytes` using `unsafe`
IIUC, bytes::Bytes is a zero-copy type, I need to implement this type but I'm not exactly understanding what the comments here are saying. Here's my attempt at implementing its conversion to and from my type Coordinate:
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Coordinate {
    pub z: u32,
    pub x: u32,
    pub y: u32,
}

impl From<bytes::Bytes> for Coordinate {
    fn from(value: bytes::Bytes) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let ptr = value.as_ptr() as *const Coordinate;
            ptr.read_unaligned()
        }
    }
}

impl From<Coordinate> for bytes::Bytes {
    fn from(value: Coordinate) -> Self {
        let ptr = &value as *const Coordinate as *const u8;
        let slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, std::mem::size_of::<Coordinate>()) };
        bytes::Bytes::from_static(slice)
    }
}

I wanted to avoid copying the data so I'm casting it to and from points. This is my first time using unsafe, soliciting general feedback; would love to understand if I'm doing this correctly. Any help's highly appreciated, thanks! :)

ptr.read_unaligned() copies the data. The From<Coordinate> for Bytes creates a dangling pointer. On top of that 3 u32 will be extraordinarily cheap to copy.

If you use your implementations on the Playground with MIRI (top right, under tools) it'll tell you it's UB, it's good practice to exercise unsafe code with miri.

I think you're confusing "zero-copy" with "cheaply clonable". Zero-copy is a property of the data type, and Coordinate is not such a type. &str and the types from rkyv are zero-copy. Bytes is cheaply clonable, which usually means calling clone will take constant time with respect to the size of the buffer.

"soliciting general feedback" is a sign you've misunderstood what [so] is about, that's explicitly off-topic. For general feedback you should ask in a discussion forum such as https://reddit.com/r/learnrust or https://users.rust-lang.org

Why do you need to implement it?

@drewtato: Minor nit, but isn't "cheaply clonable" stronger than just "takes constant time"?  If it takes hours to perform, irrespective of buffer size, I don't think anyone would consider it cheap!  I don't have a more rigorous definition however, beyond something very hand-wavy about being wait-free and requiring some relatively small number of instructions.
